# Obtain value for checked radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

The following jQuery code actually works fine in MS IE8 but returns ‘undefined’ in MS IE6.

I have also checked other questions in Stack Overflow relating to my query but cannot find any info relating to IE6. I need this code to work in both browsers (IE6 and IE8).

I have the following HTML setup for my radiogroup:

```
<input type="radio" name="f10" value="abc123"/>
```

I also have the following code that seems to work fine in IE8 but not in IE6:

```
function processJob(){
  if ($("input[name=f10]:checked").val() != undefined){
     isDelgateFlag = "Y";
     var delgSelection = $("input[name=f10]:checked").val();
  }
  else {
    isDelgateFlag = "N";
    $('#dialogdelegate').dialog('open');
    alert("Please make a selection.");
  }
}
```

As mentioned, the `$("input[name=f10]:checked").val()` seems to return a value in IE8 but returns ‘undefined’ in IE6.

How can I cater for both browsers?

Comment: Weird, $("input[name=f10]:checked").val() works just fine for me on my IE6 VPC with jQuery 1.7.2. What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: BTW IE6 is way too depreciated..Jquery is not even recommended with it

Comment: Am using jquery-1.3.2 - I will try the latest version v1.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote it `f10`

`if ($("input[name='f10']:checked").val() != undefined){`

OR Give a class to the radio button say `foo` and

```
alert($('.foo:checked').val());
```

Comment: @ahren Same here. I wouldn't even download IE6 just to test this.

Comment: Unfortunately at the company I work for, some departments are still running IE6 to cater for legacy systems and others are using IE8. The policy is that IT department need to cater for both versions until they will eventually eradicate IE6.

Comment: Appreciate the reply @ubercooluk but just tried this in IE6 and still get the 'undefined' response? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, am also using jquery-1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above responses. After upgrading both jQuery and jQuery UI libraries to the latest versions, this seemed to have solved my problems in both IE6 and IE8 browsers.

Thanks.